# Running a test across multiple Cloud Drivers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, testing, nunit

I have been spending the last 3 Months teaching myself Automated Testing. Having had no previous experience (manual tester who had never coded in my life) I have (with the help of this Board) managed to create a selenium Object Based Framework, written tests that link to this framework and got all my tests to run.

However I now need to take my test suite and pass it through multiple environments on a cloud based service. The problem I have is that I have to define the environment each time I run the test set. Ideally I want to be able to define the environments I run my tests on (Firefox, Chrome, IE etc), and then set the test suite off to run my set of 17 tests 3 times across each browser.

I Don't want to set up a system to run this locally but instead have a method that calls my different methods for my Cloud Service (currently trialling a couple)

a Sample of my code is as follows

Test Code - Login

```
namespace Kukd_Consumer_Test
{


    [TestFixture]
    public class Login : Consumer_Standard_Functionality
    {




        [Test]
        public void User_Can_Login() 
        {
           LoginPage.LoginAs("xxxxxxxxxx").WithPassword("xxxxxxx").Login();
           Assert.IsTrue(AccountPageBtns.IsAtAccountPage("Hi Richard"), "Failed to login");
           AccountPageBtns.Logout();
        }


    }
}
```

My standard Functionality (call driver go to homepage, quit etc) Currently I have to comment all but one of my Driver Methods. I want to be able to define multiples here Ideally so I can define which environments I run my tests on (locally or cloud based)

```
public class Consumer_Standard_Functionality
    {


        [SetUp]
        public void Init()

        {  
// currently have to comment out all but the one I want to run. 

            driver.InitializeChrome();
            //driver.InitializeFireFox();
            //CBT_Driver.InitialiseChromeCBT(testName);
            //CBT_Driver.InitialiseFFCBT(testName);
            //CBT_Driver.InitialiseIECBT(testName);
            //driver.InitialiseBrowserStack();
            Homepage.GoTo_HomePage();
        }


        [TearDown]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
```

My local Driver Class (plus browserstack)

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System;

namespace Kukd_Consumer_Tests
{
    public class driver
    {
        public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }



              public static void InitializeChrome()
        {
            Instance = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\richard.cariven\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Drivers\Chrome");
            Instance.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(2192, -963); 
            Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        }


        public static void InitializeFireFox()
        {
            Instance = new FirefoxDriver();
            Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        }

        public static string BSusername = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
        public static string BSpassword = "xxxxxxxxxxx";






        public static void InitialiseBrowserstack()

        {
            IWebDriver driver;

            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

            //caps.SetCapability("name", TestContext.TestName);
            caps.SetCapability("browser", "IE");
            caps.SetCapability("browser_version", "11.0");
            caps.SetCapability("os", "Windows");
            caps.SetCapability("os_version", "10");
            caps.SetCapability("resolution", "1024x768");


            caps.SetCapability("browserstack.user", BSusername);
            caps.SetCapability("browserstack.key", BSpassword);

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver
            (new Uri("http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), caps);

            Instance = driver;
        }

        public static void refresh()

        {
            Instance.Navigate().Refresh();
        }

        public static void Quit()
        {
            Instance.Quit();
        }


    }
}
```

CBT Class - Set up to pick each Cross Browser testing Parameter

```
namespace Kukd_Consumer_Tests
{
    public class CBT_driver
    {
        public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }


        public static string CBTusername = "xxxxxxxx";
        public static string CBTpassword = "xxxxxxxxxx";


        public static void InitialiseChromeCBT(string testName)
        {
            IWebDriver driver;

            var caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

            caps.SetCapability("name", testName);
            caps.SetCapability("build", "1.0");
            caps.SetCapability("browser_api_name", "Chrome56x64");
            caps.SetCapability("os_api_name", "Win8");
            caps.SetCapability("screen_resolution", "1366x768");
            caps.SetCapability("record_video", "true");
            caps.SetCapability("record_network", "true");


            caps.SetCapability("username", CBTusername);
            caps.SetCapability("password", CBTpassword);

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver
            (new Uri("http://hub.crossbrowsertesting.com:80/wd/hub"), caps);

            Instance = driver;

        }
        public static void InitialiseFFCBT()
        {
            IWebDriver driver;

            var caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

            caps.SetCapability("name", "test name");
            caps.SetCapability("build", "1.0");
            caps.SetCapability("browser_api_name", "FF46x64");
            caps.SetCapability("os_api_name", "Win8");
            caps.SetCapability("screen_resolution", "1366x768");
            caps.SetCapability("record_video", "true");
            caps.SetCapability("record_network", "true");


            caps.SetCapability("username", CBTusername);
            caps.SetCapability("password", CBTpassword);

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver
            (new Uri("http://hub.crossbrowsertesting.com:80/wd/hub"), caps);

            Instance = driver;

        }
        public static void InitialiseIECBT(string testName)
        {
            IWebDriver driver;

            var caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

            caps.SetCapability("name", testName);
            caps.SetCapability("build", "1.0");
            caps.SetCapability("browser_api_name", "IE10");
            caps.SetCapability("os_api_name", "Win8");
            caps.SetCapability("screen_resolution", "1366x768");
            caps.SetCapability("record_video", "true");
            caps.SetCapability("record_network", "true");


            caps.SetCapability("username", CBTusername);
            caps.SetCapability("password", CBTpassword);

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver
            (new Uri("http://hub.crossbrowsertesting.com:80/wd/hub"), caps);

            Instance = driver;
        }

    }
}
```

So what I need to be able to do is, in my common test so it applies to every test, loop through each of my Browsers/CBT Environments for all tests.

Am currently set up using NUnit (changed from MSTest because I have read it is easier to do this kind of thing in NUnit)

Any advice greatly appreciated, I have been advised that because I have used so many statics in my tests this may not be possible.

Regards

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and investigation I have decided to scrap my current framework and rewrite it using Xunit and a Factory Model. Once I have got this structure completed it should be easier to maintain and less brittle in future :)